# Troubles with indentfirst packages with xelatex and lualatex

Tags: xetex, luatex, indentation, polyglossia

In theory, the [indentfirst](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/indentfirst) package allows us to modify the usual behaviour in the standard classes without having to manually add an `\indent` command after each heading.

It's an extremely brief and concise package:

```
〈*package〉
\let\@afterindentfalse\@afterindenttrue
\@afterindenttrue
〈/package〉
```

but I don't understand why it doesn't work when compiling with either `xelatex` or `lualatex`.

Here is the MWE that illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{portuguese}     
\usepackage{indentfirst}     
\usepackage{lipsum}     

\title{Material de Matemática para o terceiro ano}
\author{Eu}
\date{\today}
 
\begin{document}
 
\maketitle
 
\section{Introdução}
 
\lipsum
 
\section{Exercícios}
 
\lipsum
 
\end{document}
```

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: If you load `indentfirst` *before* `polygloassia`, you get the desired outcome. Also, if you use `babel` instead of `polyglossia`, `indentfirst` works regardless of whether you load `indentfirst` before `babel` or not.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well I wanted to say that it's so brief, so few lines for a package that I think is brilliant precisely, a very good idea that makes it easy to use that code instead of typing it directly in the preamble. I'm sorry for expressing myself badly, and I hope it didn't sound offensive in any way.

Comment: @Aradnix sorry I was just joking, I'll delete the comment

Comment: polyglossia sets this based on the language so you need to coordinate with the language-specific settings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `polyglossia`, the first indentation is set on a language by language basis.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{portuguese}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\SetLanguageKeys{portuguese}{indentfirst=true}

\title{Material de Matemática para o terceiro ano}
\author{Eu}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introdução}

\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Exercícios}

\lipsum[3-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very interesting the use of the command `\SetLanguageKeys{}` that I already saw in another answer, however I was already reviewing the `polyglossia` documentation and I don't see mention to this command that looks very useful. Nor does `indentfirst` appear within the options for Portuguese (section 6.31), where only the variants for Brazilian Portuguese or Portuguese are mentioned.

Comment: @Aradnix Some years ago, the key-value interface for setting language features was dubbed experimental and it appears to have never found its way into the documentation; the `indentfirst` key is defined for every language, there may also be language specific keys.